# Sendgrid sending email but many are being deferred: status code 202

Tags: email, sendgrid, deferred, bulk-email

We are using sendgrid to send a weekly newsletter to about 50k emails. We have an authenticated domain as well as two of our own IP addresses. Our script batch sends 500 emails at a time to all the addresses with personalization. However, when we run the script, many of the emails are being processed and then being deferred according to sendgrid logs. The response is 202. Some emails receive the newsletter but others do not. Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: check the dashbord. emails is tricky, its probably going to spam and being blocked by the receiver, first check in the dashboard if you can see

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.
I would certainly follow flaxon's advice, check the dashboard and see what it says about your delivery as well as bounces or spam reports. There is a good article here on [what being "deferred" means](https://sendgrid.com/blog/delivered-bounced-blocked-and-deferred-emails-what-does-it-all-mean/) too.

I would also look into [SendGrid's Marketing Campaigns](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-marketing/). It is a better way to send bulk email, like to your 50k email list, than making several requests as you describe.